# Laravel visitor counter?

Tags: laravel

I'm a newbie. I have been coding my website for 2 weeks, and now the job is going to be finished, But I don't know how to make a simple Visitor Counter. I consider using Session to do that. Please help me to make a simple visitor counter.

Comment: Your question is too broad, be more specific

Comment: Sessions are not a persistent storage layer.  Do not store permanent data there.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do that is to keep visitor counter in a table and increment it with each request. If you want to count visits per user, you could do something like this:

```
auth()->user()->increment('number_of_visits')
```

If you need to save more data, just create a new record for each request. For example:

```
Visit::create(['ip' => $request->ip(), 'user_id' => auth()->id()])
```

Comment: By adding this in a middleware and applying added the middleware globally it will work for every request.

Answer (score 2):

-I think you should make a table called "visitors" include 3 column: ip, visited_date, hits.

-After each request to your website you save information to visitors table:

```
$ip = Request::getClientIp();
$visited_date = Date("Y-m-d:H:i:s");
$vistor = Visitor::firstOrCreate(['ip' => $ip], 'visited_date' => $visited_date]);
$vistor->increment('hits');
```